# "sudo !!" doesn't give me permissions. What am I missing?

Tags: bash

When you forgot to sudo a command you may want to write,

```
sudo !!
```

That would execute the last command applying the `sudo` command to it.

However sometimes seems I can't do that, for example inside `/etc` folders. What am I missing?

EDIT:

```
dione@saturno:/etc$ echo testing > testfile
bash: testfile: Permiso denegado
dione@saturno:/etc$ sudo !!
sudo echo testing > testfile
bash: testfile: Permiso denegado
dione@saturno:/etc$
```

Now I guess that's because it's doing sudo echo, and the problem is that redirection is not affected.

Comment: Could you give an example? The directory you happen to be in is irrelevant. Please [edit] and give us an example we can reproduce.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you're doing here because `sudo !!` does generally work.

Comment: updated. I guess I didn't take notice redirection was outside sudo effect.

Comment: should I delete the post? I don't feel you very happy with duplicate posts.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having duplicate posts, I even have some.

Comment: Duplicates are a good thing for the system. They help people with similar issues find the right solution from search engines.

Comment: hope it helps someone in the future